# Sleep all day in ramadan

Tags: fiqh, ramadan, muslim-practices

Can we just sleep all day(from sahoor to aftar) in Ramadan and woke up only for farz namaz is it permissible?
I was listening to one of the Alim he said it is completely fine sleeping all day in Ramadan.

Comment: Still need to pray, though.

Answer (score 1):

Yes its completely fine if you are sleeping whole day except farz practice because you doing your farz prayers and fast which is also farz on you it's enough and better than you woke up in whole day and watching movies or stuff which is prohibited is fasting so sleeping is better if you are not performing your nowafil practices while waking up.

Comment: Saying it is fine leaves a bad impression, you should be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Can you leave your asr prayer to the last minute so you keep your wudu for the Maghreb prayer? Can you pray while watching a soccer game? Can you just listen to Quran with double playback speed with no reflection while jogging? Can you do all your tying with your kin through formatted text messages along with  a single annual visit? You certainly can. Is it recommended? No

The prophet has said: your sleep in it (month of Ramadan) is also worship.

But I suppose the prophet didn’t say that so we’d be sleeping all day long. He just said it so we’d know that in the month of God where he’s rewarding us tenfold we don’t put too much pressure on ourselves while we are tired and we’d just know that sleeping is not a waste of time. That is also rewarding.

Sleeping all day would kind defeat the purpose of fasting, which is spiritual and mental development.

I’ve seen Muslims who sleep around 2am and wake up at 10am rather that 6am. To me that’s ok
Then I’ve seen Muslims who go sleep at 6am and wake up at 2pm, and then break their fast at 7pm. That’s a bit different, the spiritual elevation isn’t there as much.

Comment: What you say is certainly true, but it only tangentially answers the question or more exactly about 90% of your statement des address the topic of the question without being helpful to answer it.

Comment: I don't understand why it's not complete. I'm saying it's technically fine. Just not recommended at all. My examples are there to support the idea.